# Angular checkbox with boolean

Tags: angular, typescript, checkbox

I'm working on a Angular project where I need to give an use admin right. The isAdmin is a boolean (false/true). But it can't figure it how to parse the right value to the component and save the value.

```
<div class="checkbox">
   <label>
     <input type="checkbox" name="isAdmin" [(ngModel)]="user.isAdmin" [checked]="item.checked">
     Is Admin?
   </label>
</div>
```

The component.ts looks likes this:

```
this.userForm.get('isAdmin').valueChanges.subscribe(val => {
  this.newUser.isAdmin = !!val;
});
```

Can someone see what is mine mistake?

Answer (score 0):

In  your html you are using [template based forms](https://angular.io/guide/forms). But in your ts you are using a [Reactive forms](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms) approach.

So you should change your HTML to use a Reactive forms approach like the following:

```
<div class="checkbox">
   <label>
     <input type="checkbox" name="isAdmin" [formControl]="userForm.get('isAdmin')" [checked]="item.checked">
     Is Admin?
   </label>
</div>
```